# How to change password for Gentoo LiveCD in 2015?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, passwords, gentoo

I have a LiveCD from Gentoo. Gentoo still does not offer an installation option, so I planned on working from the ISO image and saving VM state after configuring the VM.

To configure the VM, I need to install software, and that requires root privileges. For root privileges, I need to know the root password, which Gentoo fails to provide. In fact, I don't even have the *gentoo* user password, so I can't SSH into the box or change the *gentoo* user's password.

Searching for how to change the password is pulling answers from 2005 to 2011 (yep, these problems have existed for over a decade...). Suggestions like *"open a root terminal and issue `passwd`"* don't work because there is no root terminal (or I can't find it by searching in the tablet interface for desktops). And suggestions like performing a Chroot don't work because there does not appear to be one setup (*`chroot <TAB>`* does not offer any suitable suggestions).

How, exactly, do I change the root password for Gentoo's LiveCD?

---

More backstory is I am not a Gentoo user. I need to test one piece of software under it because one of our users prefers the platform. After testing, I am done with it for another 3 or 6 months. Hence the reason I want to make my changes to the LiveCD image in memory, and then save the VM without jumping through all the hoops to perform an actual install.

Answer (score 3):

Opening a regular terminal and typing:

```
    $ sudo passwd
```

should take care of it. Gentoo live CDs don't have passwords, so it *shouldn't* prompt you for one when invoking sudo commands.

You **must** do this before attempting tasks that require root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

On the 2016 LiveCD, root login is disabled by default.

> Nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Find the line that begins "PermitRootLogin". Uncomment the line and set to Yes. Commented lines used to denote default values, I presume that is still the case.

> PermitRootLogin yes

Save and exit, then restart SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Media#The_occasional_Gentoo_LiveDVD) suggests invoking `sudo su -` or `sudo -i` in a terminal.